# Trying to put time delay between added TextView items in Android?

Tags: android

I'm a newbie, so please bare with a question that is likely poorly formed.  I am working on a text-based app/game where I want to display text to the user, let a few seconds pass, then display more text to the user.  This will repeat until there is a decision point, at which point the user will be presented with two buttons.

I have used the code below to show all the messages, and then the two buttons, however, I can't figure out how to put a three second delay between the TextViews (at the end of the for loop is where I think it would go I have put in a comment).*Ideally the user would get some message like Bob is typing during those 3 seconds that would then go away once the delay was over.*  I have tried using `Thread.sleep(3000)` where the comment indicates I want a delay, but it just made my app wait 24 seconds (3 seconds x 8 items in loop) before the UI was displayed.

Also, should I be doing this in onCreate, or is there a more appropriate way?

Thanks you.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //This is where I have started adding code to the app

    //This is getting the data array from my Arrays.xml file

    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] storyArray1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.storyArray1);
    String[] storyChoice1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.choiceArray1);

    //Setting up a generic linearLayout that will be used for text...
    // it is pointing to id of main layout in activity_main

    LinearLayout textLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.story_item_one);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

    //Loop that I want to use to add a TextView to the LinearLayout referenced above

    for (String text : storyArray1) {
        TextView addedTextView = new TextView(this);
        addedTextView.setText(text);
        addedTextView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.storystyle));
        addedTextView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.story_item);
        addedTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textLinearLayout.addView(addedTextView);
        //This is where I want to put in a bit of a pause... 
        //maybe with a message to the usert hat says something like Bob is typing
    }
    //This is where I would offer first choice to the user

    //Setting up a generic linearLayout that will be used for buttons...
    // it is pointing to id of main layout in activity_main

    LinearLayout buttonsLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.story_choice_one);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    buttonsLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    params2.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    params2.weight = 1;

    for (String text : storyChoice1) {
        Button addedButtonView = new Button(this);
        addedButtonView.setTransformationMethod(null);
        addedButtonView.setText(text);
        addedButtonView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.buttonstyle));
        addedButtonView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.button_item);
        addedButtonView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        addedButtonView.setLayoutParams(params2);
        buttonsLinearLayout.addView(addedButtonView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a handler

```
Handler handler1 = new Handler();
int i = 0;
TextView addedTextView = new TextView(this);

for(String text : storyArray1) 
{

    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {

            addedTextView.setText(text);
            addedTextView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.storystyle));
            addedTextView.setTextAppearance(ActivityName.this, R.style.story_item);
            addedTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
            textLinearLayout.addView(addedTextView);

        }
    }, 3000 * i );
    i += 1;
}
```

Comment: I pasted this into the code in AndroidStudio and it gives a cannot resolve error message on the `.postDelayed`.  Thoughts?

Also, it is now throwing errors on my variables text, params, and textLinearLayout saying that they are accessed from the inner class and need to be declared final.  Also, it's telling me that "this" cannot be applied to Runnable.

Comment: Apologies, I included an extra closed brace in the run() method. I also moved the text view outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using Thread.sleep() you're blocking the UI Thread and because of that your UI doesnt change. So don't use that function. You can use a handler like that

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{ 
   public void run() 
   { 
      // Actions to do after 3 seconds 
   } 
}, 3000);
```